# Make cells of BoxLayout keep size and only resize glue in java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I'm trying to make a settings panel and I want to be able to keep seeing what setting belongs to what text. So I put every jlabel with a jcheckbox or jspinner in a jpanel and then I add them to column jpanels. I have 4 column jpanels which are next to each other. In the attached images you can see 2 different width sizes. I want the red areas to be static and the blue areas to resize, because that way you can see what jlabel belongs to what setting.
[image][image]

Here I have a SSCCE

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SSCCE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
            jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(580, 113));
            jFrame.add(new SettingsPanel());
            jFrame.pack();
            jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static class Setting extends JPanel {
        public String name;
        public JComponent component;

        public Setting(String name, JComponent component) {
            this.name = name;
            this.component = component;
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel(name), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            add(component, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        }
    }

    private static class SettingsPanel extends JPanel {

        public SettingsPanel() {
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

            JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Amount of faces", new JSpinner()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Amount of vertices", new JSpinner()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Amount of textured faces", new JSpinner()));
            add(subPanel);

            add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

            subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Textures", new JCheckBox()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Priorities", new JCheckBox()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Alpha", new JCheckBox()));
            add(subPanel);

            add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

            subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("TSkins", new JCheckBox()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("VSkins", new JCheckBox()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("X data", new JSpinner()));
            add(subPanel);

            add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

            subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Y data", new JSpinner()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Z data", new JSpinner()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Triangle data", new JSpinner()));
            add(subPanel);

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I applied Camickr's answer and this was the outcome[image]
As you can see the jspinners and jcheckboxes are now not in line anymore and it looks a bit messy, but the way it resizes is the functionality I want. Here is the updated SSCCE with Camickr's answer

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SSCCE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
            jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(580, 113));
            jFrame.add(new SettingsPanel());
            jFrame.pack();
            jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static class Setting extends JPanel {
        public String name;
        public JComponent component;

        public Setting(String name, JComponent component) {
            this.name = name;
            this.component = component;
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
            add(new JLabel(name), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(50, 0)));
            add(component, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        }
    }

    private static class SettingsPanel extends JPanel {

        public SettingsPanel() {
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

            JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Amount of faces", new JSpinner()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Amount of vertices", new JSpinner()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Amount of textured faces", new JSpinner()));
            add(subPanel);

            add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

            subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Textures", new JCheckBox()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Priorities", new JCheckBox()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Alpha", new JCheckBox()));
            add(subPanel);

            add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

            subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("TSkins", new JCheckBox()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("VSkins", new JCheckBox()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("X data", new JSpinner()));
            add(subPanel);

            add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

            subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Y data", new JSpinner()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Z data", new JSpinner()));
            subPanel.add(new Setting("Triangle data", new JSpinner()));
            add(subPanel);

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the red areas to be static

Use the `Box.createRigidArea(...)` instead of the "glue".

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Invisible Components as Filler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) for more information.

Edit:

Messed up with the details of the layout managers you are using.

The problem is the SettingPanel. You are using a horizontal BoxLayout. The BoxLayout respects the maximum size of any component added to it. You are adding a JPanel which doesn't have a maximum size, so the size of each panel increases which causes the GridLayout to also increase, causing the gap in the BorderLayout components.

You want to prevent the panels from increasing in size. Simple change to prove the concept is to add the following when you add all your panels:

```
subPanel.setMaximumSize( subPanel.getPreferredSize() );
add(subPanel);
```

The better solution is to extend JPanel and override the `getMaximumSize()` method to return the `getPreferredSize()` to allow for dynamic changing of the panels preferred size.

After implementing this suggestion I suggest you remove:

```
jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(580, 113));
```

It is never a good idea to use random numbers. Let the layout manager determine the size.

When you do this you will see all the component clumped together so I suggest you change:

```
//setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 0));
```

This will give space between each label/component.

Then I would add:

```
add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(50, 0)));
//add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Do you really need the glue? The above will give fixed spacing between each panel.

Comment: So I should add the rigidArea between the jlabel and the jspinner or jcheckbox?

Comment: I updated the question to show what it looks like when adding the rigid areas.

Comment: This is almost what I wanted. I added the preferred size, because that's the size my main application will be when started, so I tried to give an identical representation of my settingspanel. I did want to keep the glue, because when you resize then the glue will make sure the extra space will be added between the components.  The only thing I have an issue with right now is that the JSpinners can only contain 1 number in them, because they are so small. Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: `I added the preferred size, because that's the size my main application` - you still miss the point. You should not be hard coding sizes. The size of your application will be determined by the size of the components added to the frame. The pack() method will size the frame. The preferred size of the frame can be change on different platforms because of the LAF on each platform.

Comment: `the glue will make sure the extra space will be added between the components.` - again the point is why do you need the panels to shift? Why do you think this is better?. Typically on a form you only resize components where it makes sense to give a component more/less space. For example a JTextArea. As space changes you see more or less of the text. Dynamically changing space between panels does not give any value to the layout.

Comment: So your original problem has been solved. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: You missed my point I think. I made that preferred size, just to get the size my main applictation is when I first start it, thus the size after the pack. I tried to replicate the sscce as good as possible. I think it would be better to resize the components instead of the empty space, now you're talking about it.

Comment: Can I update my question to include this or should I create a new one?

Comment: 1) How can you "accept" an answer if you have two question and two different people answer each question? You still haven't "accepted" this answer!!!  Not once have you even bothered to say thank you for the help you have received. 2) My comment was about the minimum size. You appear to be setting a minimum size to force a gap between the panels. My suggestion was to use the rigid area so you always have a gap. 3) Read the API for JSpinner and you will find a link to the tutorial which shows spinners that are bigger. Figure out what the difference its between the tutorial and your code.

Comment: Yeah I guess I should've thanked you. For some reason I didn't think about that. I also accepted your answer.